# Detecting street lamps from google street view with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, google-street-view

I am trying to use OpenCV to detect street lamps from Google Street View.

For now as sample I have 2000 positive images, but only 1200 are around the same ration, so I am using only this for training.

And another 2300 negative images.

Example of positive images:
[image: StreetLamp]
[image: StreetLamp]
[image: StreetLamp]
[image: StreetLamp]
[image: StreetLamp]

I tried down sampling them to different sizes, and train them, but for now the detection is really poor, when I test it with images like this:
[image: Test image[6]]

Depending on `detectMultiScale` argument I either get a lot of rectangles, including the lamps, or a few rectangles, but not including the actual lamps.

On training, I am modifying mostly height and width parameters, example of parameters: (200, 10) (150, 30), (120, 30). I tried changing also the algorithm from LBP to HAAR, but the results were similar.

1. Do you think I need more then 1000 positive sample?
2. Should I do any extra preprocessing before creating the vector file?
3. Do you have any idea on what parameters I should change to make it working?
4. Is it possible with OpenCV to detect with lamps in google street view images?

Comment: I don't think this is a good task for openCV cascade classifier, since there isn't much texture within the lamps and there's a lot of background around. Maybe you'll have some luck if you segment the lamps perfectly and add a lot of different background to each of your positive samples with opencv_createsamples tool, but no guarantee...

Comment: I will try to crop the pictures perfect, with white background seems like it would take my a lot of time, but i will try to see the results, and post it here. Unless someone else comes with an easier possible solution. Thanks

Comment: you will have to merge "random" background to them with opencv_createsamples. But as I said, there's not much texture within the lamps, so I guess LBP/HAAR will still not be the right choice. Maybe HoG would work better, but I don't know whether the lamps would have to be aligned better then.

Comment: Ok, I will look at HoG  to see if I will see something relevant, I was also thinking about this, but wasn't sure if it would make a difference. If not, probably I will look at Tensorflow Object Detection API or something else, to  solve the problem. And if that doesn't work, probably I will go with cuts + create sample.

Comment: Have you tried using as positive samples only the "lamp part" - the top and not the entire lamp post? Probably you'd get a better accuracy.

Comment: I would probably get better accuracy, but it's not so helpful, as later I will need to compute the distance to the street lamp, and I need to get also the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your samples to just the lamp with a small amount of sky around it (as I think that will help specificity rather than cropped lamp).

If the lamp-post matters to you, after finding a lamp, make a secondary search to find the post attached to it (or if there is none).  Look for a line emanating from your found lamp and trace it down to the ground.  In most of these images (and I imagine most scenarios) there will only be one clear line (the post) coming from the light.  You could use some form of color/ directional propagation to trace the post through its various curves and corners.

Comment: Thanks, I am still cutting images, I will confirm the answer if it will work

Comment: I managed to get a good detection around lamp part, but only with Tensorflow Object Detection API. Thanks